# Pytorch: why the orders of weights in ConvTranspose2d and Conv2d are different?

Tags: pytorch

Pytorch code:

```py
up = nn.ConvTranspose2d(3, 128, 2, stride=2)
conv = nn.Conv2d(3, 128, 2)

inputs = Variable(torch.rand(1, 3, 64, 64))
print('up conv output size:', up(inputs).size())

inputs = Variable(torch.rand(1, 3, 64, 64))
print('conv output size:', conv(inputs).size())

print('up conv weight size:', up.weight.data.shape)
print('conv weight size:', conv.weight.data.shape)
```

Result:

```py
up conv output size: torch.Size([1, 128, 128, 128])
conv output size: torch.Size([1, 128, 63, 63])
up conv weight size: torch.Size([3, 128, 2, 2])
conv weight size: torch.Size([128, 3, 2, 2])
```

Why the orders are different between `ConvTranspose2d (3,128)` and `Conv2d (128, 3)`?

Is it supposed to behave like this?

Answer (score 0):

The up convolution layer is really something weird to work with. Especially, when trying to understand the additional parameters `padding`, `stride` and `kernel_size`.

The focus on all these parameters is to **reverse a convolution**. In ConvTranspose2d, a stride of two, for example, does not "skip every second pixel", but generates an output shape that would have been the input shape of a conv layer producing the ConvTranspose2d input shape with the same stride/parameter configuration.

I guess for this reason, also the weight matrices are transposed between both implementations.

From the `conv2d` [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html):
[image]

From the `convTranspose2d` [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d.html):
[image]

Note that conv2d weights are of shape `(in_channels, out_channels)` and convTranspose2d weights are of shape `(out_channels, in_channels)`.